# jQuery: Grab the next <select> with a specific class in a table row

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML structure (excerpt):

```
<td>
    <select id="test1" class="pub_chooser">
        <option value="99">All Publications</option>
        <option value="40">Contract</option>
        <option value="21">Student</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td>
    <select id="thing1" class="ev_chooser"></select>
</td>
```

This is hooked up to an AJAX function to populate the second `<select>` when an option is clicked.

I'm also allowing users to clone() the table row. I now need to target the second `<select>` in my AJAX function.

How can I reliably get the next .ev_chooser `<select>` element when the pub_chooser `<select>` is clicked?

I've tried this to no avail:

```
corresponding_select = $('select .ev_chooser').nextAll();
```

Any tips?

-Matt

Comment: Because this table row can (and will) be cloned, and I only want to effect the immediate next `<select>`, not all of them.

Comment: edit to the above: someone asked why I didn't just do `$('select.ev_chooser')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the last select.

```
$('select.ev_chooser:last')
```

Or just search within the cloned element:

```
var clonedOBJECT = $(whatEverYouClone).clone();
var theSelect= $( 'select.ev_chooser', clonedOBJECT );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
corresponding_select = $('pub_chooser').closest('td').siblings().children('.ev_chooser');
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the space in the selector:

```
$('select.ev_chooser')
```

If you have space between select and the class, it searches all children of select for any element with class "ev_chooser".